# Getting an error when trying to create an except sr.UnknownValueError:

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, gtts

this is the part of the script that is messing it all up

```
def MyCommand():
    #init recongnize voice
    r = sr.Recongnize()
    r.pause_thershold = 3
    #threshold = one second, waiting to adjust threshold dependent on noise levels
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duraiton=3)
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    command = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
    print('you said:' + command + '\n')


    #loopback to continue to listen for commands if unrecognized speech is received
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print('I did not hear that')
        command = myCommand();

return command

while True:
    assistant(myCommand())

else:
    error = random.choice(error)
    talk(error)
```

Why exactly its not letting me put this in, I tried deleting and reinstalling the SR module but I had no luck. I tried to find something online but there isn't much info on what exactly is breaking this, most things that I found were issues with the actual SR module.

Comment: Can you please provide your traceback? Hard to tell which error we're trying to fix with no error message

Comment: Quick guess: `duraiton` should be `duration`. `myCommand` should be `MyCommand` (or vice versa).